# Angular 6 Leaflet: get map in service

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I need to get a map into my service in Angular 6 app. Currently I'm getting it via argument when I'm calling an init function in service and provide it via Subject from component after getting data from store. But sometimes I getting `undefined` instead a map.

My example of code:

**page.component.ts**

```
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {

    map$ = new Subject<Map>();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.store.pipe(
            select(fromStore.getData)
        )
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.mapService.doSomething(this.map$);
        })
    }

    mapReady(map: Map) {
        this.map$.next(map);
    }
}
```

**map.service.ts**

```
export class MapService {
    map: Map;
    subsription$: Subscription;

    doSomething(map$: Observable<Map>) {
        this.subsription$ = map$.subscribe(data => {
            this.map = data;
        })
    }
}
```

Are there any other option to get a map into the service?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you couldn't just access the map more directly? Seems like you've got some extra layers of indirection you might not need. Something like this:

map.service.ts:

```
export class MapService {
    map: Map = new Map();

    doSomething(map: Map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

page.component.ts:

```
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
        this.store.pipe(
            select(fromStore.getData)
        )
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.mapService.doSomething(data);
        })
    }

    mapReady(map: Map) {
        this.mapService.doSomething(map);
    }
}
```

The exact types might not quite be right since I'm not sure what `this.store` and `fromStore` are doing, but it should be easy enough to fit with however things are actually working.

Comment: calling `this.store select` is a `@ngrx/store` selector where I getting data from my store. So in your example you calling one func twice: after you getting data from store and after your map was inited. Also I don't get why you are creating a new examplar of a map and the reinit it when getting in args

Comment: Definitely no need to call things twice, it just wasn't entirely clear to me in what condition `mapReady` got called, so I did `doSomething` twice just to be safe. Do whatever makes the most sense for your app.

Comment: As for why I initialized with an empty map, I'm personally in the habit of initializing things with relevant empty values rather than `undefined` or `null` if you'd rather not follow that pattern, again, feel free to do whatever makes the most sense for your app.